Mostrar registro anterior y actual con mysql y php

Imprimir registro por dia

Amigos, tengo un problema al momento de imprimir el registro anterior y el actual.
Estoy buscando la forma de poder hacerlo de la siguiente manera:
Necesito imprimir el registro por dia, por ejemplo de lunes a domingo, los registros de una semana completa por dia

Con la consulta sql

Hasta ahora, he podido obtener los ultimos 7  registro de la tabla pero no lo estoy buscando de esa manera y realice el siguiente query pero no me ha funcionando
```
  <?php 
     $sql= "SELECT hidro_turbidez FROM ntu WHERE fecha_agua 
     BETWEEN date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 7 day) and now()"; 
     $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
     while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
      ?>  
     
      
<div class=" custom-table tabla-seis">

    <table  class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
         
          
        <tr>     
                <th colspan="2" class= blue-cell>NTU DIARIO</th>     
            </tr>

    <tbody>
   
            <tr>   
       
                <td colspan="1" class= red-cell> LUN</td>    
                 <td><?php echo $mostrar['hidro_turbidez'];?></td>    
            </tr>

            <tr>     
                <td colspan="1" class= red-cell> MAR</td>
                 <td><?php echo $mostrar['hidro_turbidez'];?></td>     
            </tr>
            <tr>     
                <td colspan="1" class= red-cell> MIER</td> 
                 <td><?php echo $mostrar['hidro_turbidez'];?></td>    
            </tr>
            <tr>     
                <td colspan="1" class= red-cell> JUEV</td> 
                 <td><?php echo $mostrar['hidro_turbidez'];?></td>    
            </tr>
            <tr>     
                <td colspan="1" class= red-cell> VIE</td> 
                 <td><?php echo $mostrar['hidro_turbidez'];?></td>    
            </tr>
            <tr>     
                <td colspan="1" class= red-cell>SAB</td> 
                 <td><?php echo $mostrar['hidro_turbidez'];?></td>    
            </tr>
            <tr>     
                <td colspan="1" class= red-cell>DOM</td> 
                 <td><?php echo $mostrar['hidro_turbidez'];?></td>    
            </tr>

        </tbody>                
    </table>
</div>

<?php 
     }
     ?> ```


Un ejemplo imagen-ilustrativo de lo que estoy buscando realizar:



Pero al momento de imprimir con php me imprimen varias tablas una sobre otra de acuerdo a los registros que se tienen, como podria hacerlo para que imprima en una sola tabla los registros por dia de esa semana. Tengo la duda si se puede imprimir en conjunto con el id de ese registro, pero como podria mostrarlo en la tabla junto con el dato que deseo ?


Tabla de la base de datos



No entiendo. ¿La tabla registro puede tener muchas filas en el mismo día o no? ¿Qué quiere decir "poder reiniciarlo para empezar de nuevo el lunes"? Lo que nos muestras que buscas son siete filas (¿o columnas?), una sola semana. ¿Entonces, porqué hay que reiniciar algo? WHERE id < id no puede funcionar, porque id = id obviamente. Pero esto me hace pensar, que quizás quieres aumentar los valores así que martes no solamente tiene el valor de registros en martes, pero la suma de lunes y martes. Y miércoles tiene la suma de lunes, martes y miércoles. ¿Es esto lo que quieres?

Pero si quieres las sumas, ¿cómo puede tener el domingo un valor más bajo que el sábado? Entonces, quizás quieres algo diferente todavía. Por favor muéstranos un ejemplo, como doce filas de la tabla y el resultado relacionado, para que entendamos lo que quieres lograr.

Te explico, el registro se carga de manera diaria, uno solo por día. Lo que estoy buscando realizar es que se vaya imprimiendo a medida que vayan pasando los días , por semana y reiniciar el ciclo al cumplirse la semana. Por ejemplo: Lunes : registro de ese día; martes : registro de eso día; miércoles: registro.. y así sucesivamente hasta completar toda la semana..Se tiene pensado mostrarlo en una tabla que muestre el dia y el registro de dicho dia

Todavía no entiendo. Puede ser que no basta mi espanol. Si tu tabla tiene una fila por día y quieres un resultado con una fila por día, y en lunes quieres que mostrar el registro de lunes, y en martes quieres que mostrar el registro de martes, etc., no hay ningun ciclo y no hay que reiniciar nada. Parece que lo que quieres es nada mas que select * from registro order by fecha. Bueno, ya te dije: muestranos datos, para hacer claro lo que quieres.

coloque mas detalles a la pregunta

mencionas que al imprimir con php se imprimen varias tablas, sin embargo, no muestras el código con el que imprimes, por lo que, ni idea de cuál es el problema. Hay mil maneras de imprimirlo.

El código con el que imprime está detallado en la descripción , lo realizó con un while

Para comenzar, tu consulta no devuelve ningún resultado, pues esta condición siempre va a devolver falso:
WHERE id < id

Recuerda que esto se va evaluando para cada registro, si estoy en el registro con id 5 el motor va a evaluar 5 < 5, y como 5 no es menor a 5, devolverá falso.
Cuando estoy en el registro 6, va a evaluar 6 < 6, que también devolverá falso y así para cada uno de los registros. El resultado es que ningún registro cumple la condición.
Ahora, para obtener lo que describes,

Puedes obtener los registros de los últimos 7 días basándote en el campo fecha y en la aritmética de fechas con la fecha actual, que obtienes con la función now(), a la que le puedes restar días valiéndote de la función date_sub(), por ejemplo:
select id, fecha, registro
  from registro
where fecha between date_sub(now(), interval 7 day) and now();


Puedes obtener la fecha del último domingo con la siguiente consulta:
SELECT DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(NOW())-1 DAY) latest_sun

Valiéndote de este truco, podrías obtener los registros de esta semana con una consulta como la siguiente:
select id, fecha, registro
  from registro
where fecha > DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(NOW())-1 DAY)




Hola que tal, la consulta no me funciona me trae solo los últimos registros no el de la semana

¿Leíste mis explicaciones? Si lo hiciste, probablemente serías capaz de ajustar lo que haga falta para que funcione como quieres. En último caso, a tu pregunta le haría falta una mejor explicación o ejemplo, pues no sé ¿qué es "el de la semana"?, si no los registros de la semana?

entiendo, segui tus recomendaciones y agregue mas detalles a la pregunta. Intente algo pero aun no me funciona
